# Snapshot agent not starting SQL Server error 15404 error code 0x54b

Tags: sql-server

I have run into this issue and I am stuck with it for hours. I have 2 databases one which is publisher and distributor and second which is subscriber I am going to use them as snapshot replication. Installation went without issues but when I look in Replication monitor publication status is ok but a subscription is "uninitialized subscription".

I checked `sqlagent errorlog` and I get same error

> Error: 15404, Could not obtain information about `Windows NT group/user`'MicrosoftAccount\MyEmail', error code 0x54b.
>
> [SQLSTATE 42000] (ConnIsLoginSysAdmin).

This really boggles me since I am being logged to the database through windows authentication but I am being seen as `ADMINRG-XXXXXX\YYYYY`.

In my security properties on "Specify the domain or machine account under which Distribution/Snapshot Agent will run" I have set it on Run under SQL Server Agent service account, but when I tried using windows account either ADMINRG-`XXXXX\YYYYY` or MicrosoftAccount\MyEmail It puked out error 3930 which I also couldn't manage to fix.

I also looked in generated scripts when I was installing publication and subscriptions, they both have parameters `@job_login` and `@job_password` set to null could this be source of issue?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is curious how I fixed it.I looked up in generated scripts at @job_login and @job_password I used my Microsoft account that is connected to my Windows account.Snapshot agent is starting up now, everything works fine. Homever I still get same error in logs tho it doesn't affect anything.